# Trying to make my dataTable in rails pretty, /src/demo_table_jui fails horribly on rails4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

I get an error (posted here) when I add the 
*= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui 
to the application.css of my rails file to try to prettify my dataTable according to the railscast 340 I get the following error in rails 4:

[image]

I believe this is what is preventing me from making my dataTables very pretty.

So zooming in makes the png viewable (insert didnt let the site zoom by clicking apparently).

In either case some other code:

`Application.css`

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require jquery-ui
*= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui
*= require_tree .
*/
```

`application.js`

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

And now my coffee/js file, I really don't use coffee so I removed that extension and just used this in my `groups.js` file (which is for my groups controller.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("#groups").DataTable({paging:true, 
                            pagingType: 'full_numbers'
    });
});
```

and my groups view...

```
<table class="display"  id="groups">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= model_cl
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding manually datatables files try to use a gem. In one of my latest projects I also try to add dataTables manually in assets directory. It was a little bit painful so I decided to use 'jquery-datatables-rails' gem and I was a great idea. Also you should try 'ajax-datatables-rails' gem. With these two gems everything work like a charm :)

Comment: I do have that in my gem `gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'`. I swear I cannot figure out what is going on....

Comment: Okay.There is a syntax error in css file. Remove '*' character on line ~ 35 or just replace:

`*= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui`
with 
`*= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables`
It should work.

Comment: What's odd is how is that a syntax error ? iit's a file from the gem

Comment: Please look here: [link](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/dataTables/src/demo_table_jui.css.scss#L44) Try to save this file in your stylesheets directory and delete that and other lines begins with '*'. Next replace `*= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui` with path to that file. Check if it helps. Another way is try to load basic css file like I wrote before.